# Performance and Touch Responsiveness in Application Built from PG build

Tags: eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I am building application on Eclipse before trying the Phonegap Build. 
But as I build Application Using local PG 2.X Library 
**and** the Same application I build using PGBuild 2.X.... I see Touch and scroll performance is great in Phonegap Build apk file. Why is that? Do PG people keeping some cookies for themselves at PG Build only..??

Comment: PG people say that they did not put anything special for applications build from cloud build.

Answer (score 0):

we built a native application on phonegap native. at it ran like a charm.
No performance issues with touch and feel